# What genre are games like Arcanists, Worm, Warlings?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for more games like the ones mentioned above.
Especially one like Jagex's Arcanists where not everyone has the same spells/weapons.

To be clear, I'm not asking for recommendations. I just need the genre so I have something to search for.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear by the title. I'll add it in the body too.

Comment: Well the title seemed to be asking one question, but the body seemed to be asking another. That's why I asked for clarification :)

Comment: We're historically very bad at defining what games are. We can tell you what a term means, but expecting is to slot specific games into terminology is generally a rather opinionated exercise.

Comment: Jagex's arcanist's is a multiplayer strategy game according to the wiki and worm is science fiction. They don't tend to have the same genre, but strategy may be the one your looking for.

Comment: @Frank Not really an off-topic question I think but really low research effort... If you google for "Worms genre" it's literally the first thing shown in wikipedia.

Comment: @Jutschge I did that and came up with "Artillery / strategy". Since English is not my native language I Google'd "Artillery" to be sure it meant what I thought it meant. Google came up with "large-caliber guns used in warfare on land." As this does not really apply to Arcanists for example, I wondered whether there was another term for it.

Comment: @JasperCatthoor they are called artillery games due to the nature of the gameplay not want is actually firing a projectile. They are called Artillery games due to having to calculate trajectory of your shot over a long distance like artillery do in real life.

Comment: @Jasper: Artillery fire is usually despicted just as the bazooka in Worms: a canon fire high in the air, and the projectile fall with a bell-like curve (ex. mortar). If Arcanist's spells works similarly to weapons in Worms (usually fire in the air, and touch the enemy when it fall back down), then the only difference is in the graphic despiction. The fact that it look like a fireball instead of a canonball doesn't matter for the mechanic classification.

Comment: Not 100% so I'm not adding an answer, but many may be considered turn-based games as well

Comment: @DrakaSAN not a bell-like curve (also called a *Gauss curve*), but a parabolic curve.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The genre of games you are looking for are very widely known as Artillery Games.

These types of games are called artillery games due to the nature of the game where the players have to calculate shots over potentially very long distances and readjusting your aim based on previous shots, much like artillery do in real life to make shots.

Comment: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_game